# How to read AJAX response variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following is the response I'm receiving in my AJAX success function:

```
"{"success":true,"data":{"id":1841,"title":"atitle","filename":"filename.jpg","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/filename.jpg","link":"http:\/\/example.com\/?attachment_id=1841","alt":"","author":"21","description":"","caption":"","name":"filename-39","status":"inherit","uploadedTo":0,"date":1415555051000,"modified":1415555051000,"menuOrder":0,"mime":"image\/jpeg","type":"image","subtype":"jpeg","icon":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-includes\/images\/media\/file.png","dateFormatted":"November 9, 2014","nonces":{"update":"b832c2939d5","delete":"83dda46357e","edit":"51ac41b11c6"},"editLink":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-admin\/post.php?post=1841&action=edit","meta":false,"authorName":"Some One","filesizeInBytes":10755,"filesizeHumanReadable":"11 kB","sizes":{"thumbnail":{"height":90,"width":90,"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/filename-90x90.jpg","orientation":"landscape"},"full":{"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/filename.jpg","height":260,"width":236,"orientation":"portrait"}},"height":260,"width":236,"orientation":"portrait","compat":{"item":"","meta":""}}}"
```

I'm trying to update the `src` attribute of a particular image on my page using the data that is returned in this response. For example:

```
$( '#myimage' ).attr( 'src', response.data.url );
```

The problem is, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

I'm sure `response.data.url` is wrong. How can I get the URL from the response so that I can update the image's `src` attribute?

Comment: can we see the full `$.ajax` code? a couple of things i'm wondering: a) are you attempting to use response.data.url in your success callback, and b) is the return data being treated as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo could use

```
x=$.parseJSON(response)
```

and this will convert the json string to a valid json objet, if there is an error will throw an exception you can use try{}catch(e){} to fix it

```
try{
var x=$.parseJSON(response);
}catch(e){
console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to take advantage of jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method. When you're using ajax, you are only receiving a string response, so you would first have to parse it as json using [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/). However, getJSON will do parseJSON for you.

```
$.getJSON('my/service', function(data) {
    $('#myimage').attr('src', data.url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I decided to use `$.parseJSON()`

Answer (score 1):

use JSON.parse to parse as an object, your returned data is string:

```
response=JSON.parse(response);
$( '#myimage' ).attr( 'src', response.data.url );
```

Comment: JSON.parse is not supported by all ie browsers he is using jQuery. i think is better to use the jQuery function (it is cross-browser)

Comment: JSON.parse() doesn't work like that. It [returns a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). ie: `var newvalue = JSON.parse(stringvalue);`

Comment: @Ernesto which browsers don't support JSON.parse?

Comment: @henrywright Internet explorer 8 and below, and he is using jQuery so it's better to use $.parseJSON that is supported by IE8 and IE7

Comment: @Ernesto `$.parseJSON` done the job perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @kaxi1993 I decided to opt for full browser support and use `$.parseJSON` - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use an `AJAX` request like this:

```
$.post('remote_url', {key:value}, function(response){
    if(response.success) {
        $('#myimage').attr('src', response.data.url);
    }
}, 'json');
```

In this example, I've used `$.post` and you didn't provide enough information about the request type so it could be a `$.getJSON` request as well. Also, `{key:value}` is an object which will be passed to the server if required. So, use it if you pass any data to server, otherwise remove it.

In this example, `'json'` is being used as data type so the response will be parsed by `jQuery` also if you use `$.getJSON` then the response will be parsed but in this case, you don't need to use `'json'` as the last parameter. For example:

```
$.getJSON('remote_url', function(response) {
    if(response.success) {
        $('#myimage').attr('src', response.data.url);
    }
});
```

**Note:** `getJSON` loads JSON-encoded data from the server using a `GET` HTTP request. So, for a `POST` request use `$.post` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I decided to use a simple `response = $.parseJSON( response.response )` which then let me do `response.data.url`